# uiwebview doesnt respond to orientation change

Tags: ios, uiwebview, orientation

```
UIViewController *webViewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UIWebView *uiWebView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)]   autorelease];
[webViewController.view addSubview: uiWebView];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
```

i want to allow orintation change to this web view. how to achieve this?
also , if i navigate from previous view which is landscape, web view gives blank space on right. please help to fix this also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default implementation of `-[UIViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation :]` returns `YES` for portrait orientation **only**.  For other orientations, it returns `NO`.

You must create a subclass of `UIViewController`.  In your subclass, you must override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` to return `YES` for all the orientations you want to support.  Use an instance of your subclass instead of using a basic `UIViewController`.